# onLayout is not invoked for right item when sued inside loop

Tags: react-native

I render items in a loop and I need to get each item Y position so I can use `scrollTo()` to scroll to that position later on event.
Problem is that it seems that `onLayout` is not called correctly so I am getting wrong item positions.
Example items:

```
A,B,C,D
```

but I get stored position sometimes for A, sometimes for C etc.
How can I synchronise this?

```
this.props.list.map((item, index) => {
   return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onLayout={(event) => {
          let {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
....
```

**UPDATE**
Here is full code. So you see I set first country index that I find in `onLayout`. So when I press **B** it should scroll to position of **Bahamas** but instead it sometimes scroll to **Bahamas** and sometimes to **Barbados** and sometimes to **Bhutan**...

```
const countries = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan"];

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      currentLetter: "A",
    };

    this.sections = {}
  }

onLetter(letter) {
    this.setState({currentLetter: letter});
    if (this.sections[letter]) {
      this.scrollView.scrollTo({ y: this.sections[letter] });
    }
  }

<ScrollView ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}>
          {
            countries.map((item) => {
              return (
                <View onLayout={(event) => {
                  var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                    if (!this.sections[item[0]]) {
                      this.sections[item[0]] = y;
                    }
                  }}
                  style={{backgroundColor: "#f0aabb", padding: 10, margin: 5}}>
                  <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>
              )
            })
          }
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Are you using a FlatList?

Comment: No. I am using scrollviewI can’t change that.

Comment: Well, that behaviour would be explained by a flatlist, since it hides items to increase performance but the scrollview renders everything. Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: That is what I don’t want I want to scroll to item not to hide anything. This is like i iphone contact book with alphabet on the side when I drv over letters scrollview should go to specific position.

Comment: Got it. Usually what I do is know the height from the beginning and calculate the amount of items to calculate the offset, but cant know for sure with the code you have. Maybe there isd another issue

Comment: Can you give a code example that replicates your problem?

Comment: I updated questions

Comment: Can't you use a `SectionList`? It seems like it would solve your problem and be a much more performant solution. Here's a Snack example of something like you want to achieve https://snack.expo.io/Hy2Y_xkBE

Comment: @1110 are all your rows the same height?

Comment: Yes in the end I gave up and make all items same height and calculate scroll index

Comment: @1110 yeah that is what I was going to suggest. I had a solution for iOS that used `UIManager` but on Android `UIManager` doesn't give the results that you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `onLayout` doesn't go on order. So not sure if Bahamas will go first.

I think you should create a func for mapping letter and starting/pointing item, like: 'A' = 'Afghanistan', 'B' = 'Bahamas'

You can hard-code it (not recommend, just explain the idea)

```
dataSource = { 'Afghanistan': 'A', 'Bahamas': 'B'}
// implement this func base on your rules for title and letter
getLetterFromTitle(title) {
  return dataSource[title];
}
```

then `onLayout`

```
const letter = getLetterFromTitle(item);
if (letter && !this.sections[letter]) {
  this.sections[letter] = y;
}
```